# Java formula evaluation library with out-of-order variables feature

Tags: java, parsing, math, formula

I'm currently looking for a java library (or native library with a java API) for formula parsing and evaluation.

Using recommandations from here, I took a look on many libraries :

- JFormula
- JEval
- Symja
- JEP

But none of them fulfil my needs, that are :

- Multiple formula evaluation with dependency between them (a formula is always an affectation to a variable using other variables or numerical values)
- Possibility to change only one formula out of maybe 50, with good performances if only one formule changes
- no need to handle by hand variables dependancies
- Automatically update other dependant variables if a formula changes
- Possibility to listen which variable changed
- no need to have a specific format for the variables (the user will directly enter a name and doesn't want to have a complexe notation)

Maybe an exemple will be better. Let's say we have, entered in the system in this order :

- a = b + c
- c = 2 * d
- b = 3
- d = 2

I would like to be able to enter those 4 lines in this order, and ask for the result of "a" (or "b", whatever).
Then if in the user interface (basically a table variable <> formula) "b" is changed to "2 * d", the library will automatically change the value of "b" and "a", and return me (or lunch an event, or call a function) a list of changes

The best library would be one just like JEP, but with the out-of-order variables capability and the possibility to auto-evaluate dependant variables

I know that compilers and spreadsheet softwares uses such mechanisms, but I didn't found any java or java compatible libraries directly usable

Does someone know one?

EDIT : Precision : the question is really about a library, or eventually a set of libraries to link together. The question is for a project in a company and the idea is to spend the minimum amount of time. The "do it yourself" solution has already been estimated and is not in the scope of the question

Comment: So you're trying to solve *simultaneous equations?*

Comment: Not really, we shouldn't have neither dependency cycles nor at least one formula per variable in formulae, but maybe a lot of dependency levels

Comment: no idea how to help, but good luck!

Comment: one quick way would be to write a simple parser to identify each tokens inside each equations, hence the dependancies of one equation to others. this will then allow you to inject them in the correct order to jep.

Comment: Thanks ! But we would like to avoid implementing by hand parsing and dependancies

Comment: @cporte, parsing is always *trivial*, unless you're parsing some awful abomination like `C++`. It is just so unfairly overrated! Dependencies are also easy to handle, it's nothing but a DAG, you must have tons of libraries to deal with all kinds of graphs.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explained the point of view correctly :). Doing it ourselves is not a technical issue and if no libraries are available, then it will be done like that. But all the overhead about project management, technical controls, testings, scientific validation, etc. are just a pain here (don't ask why, you really don't want to know ^^)

Comment: @cporte, sounds like you're working in a horrible place. But why such an inconsistency? Why you're not supposed to test and verify rigorously any external library you're using?

Comment: Have you tried searching a library that fulfills your requirements in a functional language like Lisp? If there is, maybe there is a bridge to communicate from Java to this external library that will do the dirty work for you.

Answer (score 1):

For a project that I also needed a simple formula parser I used the code of the article [Lexical analysis, Part 2: Build an application](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-02-1997/jw-02-indepth.html?page=1) in javaworld.com. It's simple and small (7 classes), and you can adapt it to your needs.

You can downdoad the source form [here](http://www.mcmanis.com/~cmcmanis/java/javaworld/) (search for 'Lexical Analysis Part II' entry).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of any libraries.

Assuming what you have is a set of equations with a *single* variable on at least one side of the equation (A+B=C-D is disallowed) and  *no* cycles, (e.g., A=B+1; B=A-2), what you technically need to do is to build a a data flow graph showing how each operator depends on its operands.  For side-effect-free equations (e.g., pure math) this is pretty easy; you end up with a directed acyclic graph (a forest with shared subtrees representing shared subexpressions).   Then if a value of a variable is changed, or a new formula is introduced, you revise the dag and re-evaluate the changed parts, propagating changes up the dag to the dag roots.  So, you need to build trees for the expressions, and then share them (often by hashing on subtrees to find potential equivalent candidates).    So, lots of structure manipulation to keep the dag (and is root values)

But if its only 50 variables of the complexity you show, it would act, you could simply reevaluate them all.  If you store the expression as trees (or better yet, reverse polish) you can evaluate each tree quite fast, and you don't pay any overhead to keep all those data structures up to date.

If you have hundreds of equations, the dag scheme is likely a lot better.

If you have *constraint* equations (e.g., you aren't restricted as to what can be on both sides), you're outside the spreadsheet paradigm and into constraint solvers, which is a far more complex technology.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But I'm really looking for a library. We know how to implement it but we don't have resources to design, implement, test, debug, etc. and we will do that only if we don't have any other solution

Comment: The "simply re-evaluate up to 50 equations" is pretty easy to implement, if you can implement *1* equation, and that is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Why would not you just write your own? Your assessment of complexity of this task might be wrong. It is much easier than you might think - chances are, learning how to deal with any 3rd party library would require much more effort than implementing such a trivial thing from scratch. It should not take more than a couple of hours in the worst case.

It does not make any sense to look for 3rd party libraries for doing simple things (I know, it is a part of the Java ethos, but still...)

I'd recommend to take a look at the [Cells](http://common-lisp.net/project/cells/) library for inspiration. It is in Common Lisp, but ideas are basic enough to be transferred anywhere else.

Comment: Technically yes, it's not really complex... for now. If we don't use a 3rd party library, it will become an internal project here and it will become a nightmare (fear the management !).
I was only surprised that no good 3rd library exists for that, but all the replies and comments seems to indicate that it's a fact.
That's also why I limited the scope of the question. My question is not "how to do it ?" but "did someone already done that and shared it, because we have funnier stuff to do here" :)

Comment: @cporte, how a couple of hundreds LoC can ever become a nightmare? An unnecessary external dependency is a nightmare, always. That's why you'll never find a ready to use generic enough library for something as trivial as this.

Comment: Again, the nightmare is not the technical part, but we're really getting off topic now. Thanks again for you replies and I totally understand your point of view (And I'm totally agree with you, by the way :), maybe except for the "never find a ready to use lib", as it would only take a few efforts on JEP to make it ready). If you've some free time and motivation, maybe you can give here an architecture proposal/overview of a "by hand" solution, it will always be useful for me and other people with same needs. Anyway, thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

you can check these links too...

- MathPiper (a Java fork of the Java Yacas version) (has it's own
  editor based on jEdit) (GPL) http://code.google.com/p/mathpiper/
- Symja/Matheclipse (my own project, uses JAS and Commons Math
  libraries) (LGPL) http://krum.rz.uni-mannheim.de/jas/
- Java Algebra System (JAS) (LGPL) http://krum.rz.uni-mannheim.de/jas/

Answer (score 0):

I would embedd [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/), see the Tutorial about embedding [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy). [Freeplane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeplane) (a Java Mindmapper) also uses Groovy for formulas.

Whenever a variable is changing you have to put the new value into the binding.
All the cell code should be given to the Groovy Shell as single code piece. You can register on changes via [BindPath](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/binding/BindPath.html).

Anyway I assume you have to implement a thin layer to fullfill your requirements:

- no need to handle by hand variables dependancies
- Possibility to listen which variable changed

Comment: More and more libraries are embedding Groovy just for easier configuration (instead of XML they are using groovy). Groovy 2.0 have beend modularized to keep the size down. For example logback, maven 3 polyglot, Freeplane, ...

Comment: No wonder the code we get is bloated beyond belief.  Some guy wants a subroutine, and the proposal is that he include an entire sublanguage to get some features he might be able to use.

Comment: We are talking about JSR 223: Scripting for the Java Platform - http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223 - http://groovy.codehaus.org/JSR+223+Scripting+with+Groovy - but you certainly know better.